# What are these parts described by the service manual?

Tags: repair, appliances, dryer, washing-machine

The [service manual for a LG WM3677HW](http://www.appliancefactoryparts.com/content/pdfs/125464-2.pdf) shows a very bad diagram... and I'm not very familiar with the parts to ID them.

[image: detail from service manual]

The image above tells me to probe 3 components, and if out of spec replace them.

The dry heather resistance I can guess is the middle one (bulkier and solder instead of simpler connectors. the others two I need help.

Here's the picture of the actual part:

[image: actual image of part]
(image is huge! right click and View Image on new tab)

any clues about what is what?

---

Edit:
Just went and measured all the 3 points. I hope the 1st one in the diagram is the middle one in the picture... then the other 2 would be open, resulting in no part needing replacement, right? ...regardless of what they are?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Center one is the element. You can tell because it has a metal outer tube, white ceramic filler and a center nichrome wire which is the heating element. It is a loop and each end of the loop is the spade terminals attached to the center nichrome wire. This is a typical build for an immersion heating element.

[image: Element]

On the other two, it's a moot point which is which as they're both showing continuity at two tenths of an ohm and should be ok.

The thermal fuse would be showing infinity if it failed and is probably the one on the left. It will be long, rectangular and the body projects into the hot water stream so it will fail if it gets overheated.

The right side item looks big enough (round center section with two wings that have the spade terminals) to have one of those snap action thermal discs and is probably the thermostat.